# Overriding FSGetCatalogInfo via dlsym

Tags: c, macos, dll-injection, dyld, dlsym

I'm trying to get override the FSGetCatalogInfo function under OS X Lion 10.7 using DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES, and everything works correctly up to the point that I actually call the original FSGetCatalogInfo function, at which point I get a "Bus Error: 10".

My code snippet is:

```
OSErr (*original_FSGetCatalogInfo) (const FSRef *,FSCatalogInfoBitmap,FSCatalogInfo *,HFSUniStr255 *,FSSpecPtr,FSRef *) = NULL;

OSErr FSGetCatalogInfo (const FSRef *ref,FSCatalogInfoBitmap whichInfo,FSCatalogInfo *catalogInfo,HFSUniStr255 *outName,FSSpecPtr fsSpec,FSRef *parentRef)
{
    if(!original_FSGetCatalogInfo) {
        printf("== FSGetCatalogInfo - creating shim link ==\n");
        original_FSGetCatalogInfo = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "FSGetCatalogInfo");
        printf("== FSGetCatalogInfo - created shim link ==\n");
    }

    printf("== FSGetCatalogInfo - calling original function ==\n");
    OSErr oserr = original_FSGetCatalogInfo(ref,whichInfo,catalogInfo,outName,fsSpec,parentRef);
    printf("== FSGetCatalogInfo - called original function ==\n");
    return oserr;
}
```

I'm thinking I must be either defining or calling the original FSGetCatalogInfo wrong, but I can't figure out exactly where I'm screwing up - ideas?